# ¿Cómo llamar procedimientos almacenados con Sequelize?

Tags: mysql, nodejs, sequelize.js, sequelize

Intento llamar un procedimiento almacenado de MySQL desde mi controlador, el método que utilizo es el siguiente:

```
productController.read = async (req, res) => {
    const data = await Product.sequelize.query("ListProducts();", { type: QueryTypes.SELECT })
        .then(function (properties) {
            res.json(properties)
        })
}
```

Pero me arroja el siguiente error:

```
{
    code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
    errno: 1064,
    sqlState: '42000',
    sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ListProducts()' at line 1",
    sql: 'ListProducts();',
    parameters: undefined
  },
  sql: 'ListProducts();',
  parameters: {}
}
```

Pero si lo ejecuto con **.findAll()** este si me muestra resultado, entonces, ¿Cuál sería la sintaxis correcta para llamar procedimientos almacenados de un **CRUD** en **MySQL** usando **Sequelize**?

Comment: Intente: `... await Product.sequelize.query("CALL ListProducts();", { type: QueryTypes.SELE ...`.

Comment: Funcionó, muchas gracias. ¿Y si necesitaría pasarle algún parámetro?

Comment: Use: `... await Product.sequelize.query("CALL ListProducts(:nombre_param1);", {replacements: {nombre_param1: "nombre_param1_valor"}, type: QueryTypes.SELE ...`.

Comment: Muchas gracias.